# Create Unique id in rails while saving records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am performing bulk operations in rails application.In my application i am selecting mac address from UI(In Check boxes) to getting status of selected mac address and saving results into db.Now i have to show last execution details of selected mac address after getting status.For that i need to save some unique id for each execution.Below the results which needs to be stored in DB.Whenever i am executing id should be unique.How to create unique id in rails? If unique id is already present in db,it has to create some random number for each execution.

```
MacAddress    Status    id

6A:56:78:88   Online     1

78:88:98:90   Offline    1

//Next Execution
6A:56:78:88   Online     2

78:88:98:90   Online      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is reserved name and you can not have it as a column name.
by default any record you save they will get unique id so you dont need to be worried about this.
`Produc.create(mac_address: "6A:56:78:88", status: "Online")` will create new record with unique id. 
Mac address is already has unique value to refer to, as there is no two device with same mac address (or at least it shouldn't be) 
so for finding your record `Product.find_by(mac_address: "6A:56:78:88")` will give you a right record.

If you want to take control of id number which you are saving as primary key then this can be a good solution:

```
unique_id = rand(2**32..2**64-1) 
while !Product.where(mac_address: unique_id).blank?  do
  unique_id = rand(2**32..2**64-1)
 end
new_product = Product.create(id: unique_id, mac_address: "6A:56:78:88", status: "Online")
```

If you want to generate unique code as string and index it then:

```
unique_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
new_product= Product.create(id: unique_id, mac_address: "6A:56:78:88", status: "Online")
```

Comment: Thanks.I will check this.